# Use variable in another function then call the new function

Tags: javascript, variables

Here I'm trying to use a variable in function New(), the variable was created in the function Test().

I'm still a bit confuse about how to use global variable.

```js
function New(){
Test();
//this show nothing  
alert(myName);
}

function Test() {
    myName = "John";
}


New();
```

Even when I do "var myName;" outsise of these functions, it doesn't work.

Still searching

Comment: Your code above works for me. But, you still don't have myName declared with var, so it is implicitly global.

Comment: Actually its an example, i'm using multiple function with global variable in meteor, i guess this one works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ec7h2ewn/)

things to change :

1) use `function New(){}` instead of `function New{}`

2) return myName from test function and store it in new variable in New function

```
function New(){

var myName= Test();

//this show nothing  
alert(myName);
}

function Test() {
   var myName = "John";
    return myName
}   

New();
```

**update : yeah u can also define myName as global variable and use it**

Comment: Thanks man it was easy, well it's friday sorry my brain's off

Comment: @teddym  my pleasure. well, it happens sometimes :D XD

Answer (score 0):

When you want to declare a variable for use, use the var keyword. When you do this, the location of where you do it determines the "scope" of the variable. If you want to use the variable in two functions, you can simply declare the variable outside of both:

```
 var myVariable = "Something";

 function1(){  
    myVariable = "something else";
 }

 function2(){  
    myVariable = "something else again";
 }
```

Another way to share data is to pass that data as arguments into a function:

```
 function1(){  
    var myVariable = "Something";
    function2(myVariable);
 }

 function2(someName){  
    alert(someName); // "Something"
 }
```

In your case, you didn't use the "var" keyword to declare your variable, so it became global, but you have a typo in your code, so it didn't run.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `myName` globally, then define `myName` in the return of `Test()` function. When declaring a function, always use keyword "function", "()", and "{}" no matter what.

```js
var myName;

function New() {
  
alert(Test());
}

function Test() {
   myName = "John";
   return myName;
}


New(Test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just a small type error. Just add braces after New

```
var myName;    // have myName global ie, outside all functions

function New(){      // needs the braces() for New to be a function
    Test(); 
    alert(myName);
}

function Test() {
    myName = "John";
}


New();
```

Answer (score -1):

Global variable is something whose scope is for a particular class and not restricted to a function.

You can create variable myName inside class but outside function and use it anywhere within class.

```
var myName="";

function New{
Test();
//this show nothing  
alert(myName);
}

function Test() {
    myName = "John";
}


New();
```

Comment: Despite having a "class" keyword, JavaScript does not use actual classes. A global variable is simply a storage location that is attached to the host environment's global object. In a browser, that is the window object.